# Magnitude of Complex Numbers in Array

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have the following array:

```
complex = [4+1j, 4+ 0j , 4 + 2j]
```

is there an efficient way to convert to the magnitude( like this pseudo code):

```
mag = np.magnitude(complex) = [sqrt(17), 4, sqrt(20)]
```

thanks

Comment: Yes it's called `abs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `numpy.abs`:

```
np.abs([4+1j, 4+ 0j , 4 + 2j])
```

Output:

```
array([4.12310563, 4.        , 4.47213595])
# == array([sqrt(17), sqrt(16), sqrt(20)])
```